# WebForm WebMethod in ASP.NET and its impact on web.config

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

I was experimenting with a WebMethod in an ASP.NET application, the kind used in the web form.  I looked at the web.config and found the following there, and am wondering if all of these entries are required, or if there's some sort of duplication bug in Visual Studio:

```
system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ClientServicesSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ClientServicesSoap1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ClientServicesSoap2" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ClientServicesSoap3" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ClientServicesSoap4" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ClientServicesSoap5" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ClientServicesSoap6" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Comment: For config, it seems you are invoking web service ( `asmx`) from ajax.By the way, what is the question here?

Comment: The question is "I am wondering if all of these entries are required or if there's some sort of duplication bug..."

Comment: I think you have added web service reference multiple times, and that made this change.

Comment: Thanks, it does appear to be unrelated to the WebMethod.